# How to write /upload file test with mockito?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, mockito, spring-test, mockmvc

I'm trying to /upload test. It is my method:

```
@PostMapping("/upload")
    public FileClass upload(MultipartFile file,
                               Long id,
                               @RequestParam(required = false, defaultValue = "false") Boolean isFile
    ) {
        return getService().upload(file, id, isFile);
    }
```

and my test class below:

```
@Test
    public void upload() throws Exception {

        MockMultipartFile mockMultipartFile =
                new MockMultipartFile("test", "test.txt", "multipart/form-data", "test".getBytes());

                getMockMvc().perform(multipart("/upload")
                        .file(mockMultipartFile)
                        .param("isFile","false")
                        .header("authorization", getToken()))
                .andExpect(status().isOk());

    }
```

This test return 404 error:
***java.lang.AssertionError: Status expected:<200> but was:<404>***
What is my fault?

Comment: This is a question about SprintTest, not mockito. MockMvc is a SpringTest concept. There's not enough information here to determine the cause of your error. A couple of guesses might be that the parent class of your `@Post` function might give it a parent path, or the spring context that you load to make your MockMvc may not have the controller class wired into it.

Comment: There is this url on class mapping
@Controller("file") public class FileController{ ... I added this url and updated .perform(multipart("file/upload") but response didnt change . I still get 404 error

Comment: How is id to be mapped?